Intuition of $\partial_n \circ \partial_{n+1}=0$ for simplicial complexes
I am preparing a talk which presents motivational examples for homological algebra and derived categories. In that talk I am explaining intuitively what a hole is and then a way on how to algebraically translate this definition using homological algebra. As an example I introduced what an $n$-dimensional hole is. It follows the slide for that:

I then proceed to explain simplicial homology at the torus when I arrive at the chain complex $C_{n+1}(X) \overset{\partial_{n+1}}{\to} C_{n}(X) \overset{\partial_{n}}{\to} C_{n-1}(X)$ of a simplicial complex $X$.
I translate the kernel $\ker \partial_n$ as the set of $n$-dimensional boundaryless subcomplexes. The image $\mathrm{im} \partial_{n+1}$ is translated as the set of $n$-dimensional subcomplexes which are the boundary of an $(n+1)$-dimensional subcomplex. This is then the analogy to the definition of the hole from the above slide which then leads to the following slide:

Now, the question is:
When I talk about the chain complex $C_{n+1}(X) \overset{\partial_{n+1}}{\to} C_{n}(X) \overset{\partial_{n}}{\to} C_{n-1}(X)$ I want to give a short intuitional argument why this is even a complex in the first place, i.e. $\mathrm{im} \partial_{n+1} \subset \ker \partial_n$. In words, I would like to know if there is some intuition why an $n$-dimensional submanifold has empty boundary if it is the boundary of an $(n+1)$-dimensional submanifold.
Some thoughts I had were:
We can show that this is a complex simply by substituting the definition of the boundary map $\partial_n$ for simplicial complexes. $\partial_n \circ \partial_{n+1}$ is then zero because the terms all cancel each other. This cancelling probably could be explained with some nice intuition but I did not come up with something.

Here's my intuition:

The boundary of a manifold is its closure minus the manifold itself. $\partial M=\overline M\backslash M$. Intuitively, this is because manifolds are modelled on open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, where this is true.
A closed manifold has no boundary, since its closure is the manifold itself. $\partial M=\overline M\backslash M=M\backslash M=\emptyset$.
The boundary $\partial M$ of a manifold is a closed manifold (Intuitively this is because its accumulation points must also be accumulation points of $M$ itself and are thus already contained in $\partial M$), therefore $\partial(\partial M)=\emptyset$.


I like that intuition. Though in the context of the talk it may be too analytical perhaps or there might just be an intuition which could be better suited to the above examples. Anyway, that already is pretty nice and helps a lot!


Intuition of "An  n-dimensional submanifold has empty boundary if it is the boundary of an  (n+1)-dimensional submanifold"

Your title is about geometry whereas the question itself talks mostly algebra.  As far as the geometric intuition is concerned, to fix ideas let's assume we are in a 3-manifold $M$.  By definition a manifold $M$ with boundary at a point $p$ of the boundary looks like a half-ball, where the bottom 2-disk is centered at $p$.  But this means precisely that the boundary $\partial M$ is a smooth surface at every point $p\in \partial M$ (every point of the surface is the center of a neighborhood diffeomorphic to a disk, which is what it means to be a smooth surface without boundary).

I understand that the title may be misleading or sets maybe a wrong expectation. I will edit it to better suit the question. To the part of your answer however: I do not really understand that and I myself have too little knowledge/intuition for manifolds in general. I thus think that it does not answer my question.
